# use-package's :after directive

Tags: use-package

I saw that use-package has an [`:after`](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package/blob/master/use-package.el#L1055-L1056) section that can be used, which:

> Defer loading of a package until after any of the named features are loaded.

The wording uses "any" instead of "all", so would that mean that if I set something like `:after one two three`, it will start loading even if only `one` is loaded but not `two` and `three`? The [source](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package/blob/master/use-package.el#L870-L878) seems to show that this is the case, but I'm not entirely sure.

If this *is* the case, though, what is the point of specifying more than one feature? Wouldn't it be preferable to defer until *all* of the specified features are loaded?

I have trouble envisioning a scenario in which it would be useful to defer a package until *any* of the specified features is loaded. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the purpose of `:after`?

Comment: Say you want to use a spellchecker when writing some latex or when putting down some notes in org-mode. It makes sense to defer the loading of the spellchecker until after either your favorite latex-mode or org-mode is loaded. I'm pretty sure that there are cleaner ways of achieving this, though.

Comment: Ohhh! I guess the idea is that if, in your example, a hypothetical 'latex' package were deferred, and so was a hypothetical 'org' package, `:after (latex org)` would essentially defer package X until either one of them was loaded, since X would be needed for either one. I guess that sounds obvious now that I say it, but I was pretty confused. I feel like that answered my question. If you like, write it up as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Neither `latex-mode` nor `org-mode` are hypothetical (`;)`) but that's the idea. I'll post an answer if nobody can come up with something better... this usecase still leaves me uncomfortable as "not the proper way".

Comment: Haha I am aware, but I don't think you would write `:after (latex-mode org-mode)`. It seems like you would have to write the feature names that define `latex-mode` and `org-mode` no? Any ideas on how to figure out what those are reliably? I tried `c-h f latex-mode` for example to see which file it was defined in and to see if that had a `(provides 'blah)` form, but I couldn't find any.

Comment: Org's feature is `org`; Latex is more complicated: apparently the built-in mode provides `tex-mode` and AUCTeX provides `tex`. But any of the subfiles would work, for example `latex` is provided by `latex.el` in AUCTeX and would work.